# How to show product description complete html (not only text) on product listing page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show product short description in product boxes. I am using this,

```
<?php if ( $description_words_limit > 0 ) { ?>
  <div class="atgrid__item__description">
    <?php echo adventure_tours_get_short_description( $item->post ); ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The function:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'adventure_tours_get_short_description' ) ) {
/**
 * Returns short description for current post or for the specefied post.
 *
 * @param  WP_Post $forPost    optional post object (if empty - current post will be used).
 * @param  int     $word_limit max allowed words count.
 * @return string
 */
  function adventure_tours_get_short_description( $forPost = null, $word_limit = null ) {
    $resetPost = ! empty( $forPost );
    if ( null === $forPost ) {
      $forPost = get_post();
    }

    if ( ! $forPost ) {
      return '';
    }

    $text = $forPost->post_excerpt ? $forPost->post_excerpt : $forPost->post_content;
    if ( $text ) {
      return adventure_tours_do_excerpt( $text, $word_limit );
    } else {
      return $text;
    }
  }
}
```

This code prints short description text, but I want complete html. 
How can I do this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `adventure_tours_get_short_description()` is not a WordPress function. Unless you share that function, we likely can't help you.

Comment: @mevius ! I have added function., see if this can help